# Group items? Form

Tags: html, css

For fun I have taken a piece of code I got from a friend and tried to create a login field with username and password and I am having a hard time get the fields next to the words. There is a big gap between the word username and the box you type in.The same applies for password.

This is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.mattepunkten.com/action_login.php"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="http://www."here you write url to webpage one should be directed to when typing wrong login".com"> 
        Username: 
    <input type="text" name="fld_userid" size="15" style="width: 120px"><br> 
        Password: 
    <input type="password" name="fld_password" size="15" style="width: 120px"><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="cmd_invia" value="Login"> 
</form>
```

And my css code is the following.

```css
input {
    color: black;
    margin: 10px 100px 0px 400px;
}
form {
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

I am pretty new at this and would appreciate some tips! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have such huge margins? 100px? 400px?!

Comment: @RocketHazmat optimized for mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

Well your margins are huge, try to make them smaller and see how it looks:

```
input {
    color: black;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

The style you are using has the following format:

```
margin: <top> <right> <down> <left>;
```

So with 100px right and 400px left they will get very far away :)

To be able to style the text you need it to be an element, so a simple answer would be to wrap it in some tag, but this is a style I personally enjoy, and adds a lot more meaning:

#### html

```
<label>
    <span>Username:</span>
    <input name="fld_userid">
</label>
```

#### css

```
label { display: block; text-align: center; }
input, span { display: block; width: 200px; }
```

This should stack both the text and the input on top of each other, while keeping them grouped by the label, so when you interact with the text the browser properly focus its related input.

Comment: Yes, that helped! But I realised I did not ask the question properly. I want to get the words username and password centered on the page (and still close to the boxes), how do I do that?

Comment: I set the margins very high in order to get the boxes in the center, the text however remained to the left.

Comment: To be able to style the text you need it to be an element, so a simple answer would be to wrap it in some tag, making it a <span> for example, but I'm expanding my answer to include a better suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried putting username and password inside span tags and then text align it with css to center, but nothing happened. I must be doing something wrong. is it enough to write <span>username</span>?

Answer (score 0):

I will add an explanation

```
margin: 10px 100px 0px 400px;
```

stands for:

```
top margin is 10px
right margin is 100px
bottom margin is 0px
left margin is 400px
```

Comment: Yes, I know that! My problem is that I don´t know how to move both the text and the input boxes together. I want them to be in the center of the page.

Comment: try this:
form {
    text-align: center;
}

Comment: I have tried it and unfortunately it does not help. The only thing that happens is that the "login" button moves a little bit sideways.

Comment: I'm sorry. But it work properly in my browser with your given code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried working with labels at all - keeping it semantic, and formatted, plus if you wrap your `inputs` it'll give it a larger hit area for said fields. In addition - I removed the input margin, removed the forms positioning and float so it retained it's block level, and adjusted the overall `form` margin so it's centered.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.mattepunkten.com/action_login.php"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="#"/> 

    <label>Username: 
    <input type="text" name="fld_userid" size="15"/><label>

    <label>Password: 
    <input type="password" name="fld_password" size="15"/></label>

    <input type="submit" name="cmd_invia" value="Login"/> 
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
    display: block;
}
form {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/kad7yy1L/

Comment: Cool! I have never worked with labels before but it was a nice solution to this problem. Now I have with your help managed to get them in the middle, but it seems like the password box is slightly more to the left than the username box. They are not in line if you understand what I mean. How can I fix this? I guess putting an extra space will not do any good... :)

Comment: Ah I see now - well with how that fiddle is setup it's tricky ( I'll set up another ) - but you can break the labels out and add a `<label for="userid">User Id</label>` and have `<input id="userid"/>` so it has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Its better form to contain your labels in a `<label>` tag.

For example:

```
<div class="form-element">
  <label for="foo">Label</label>
  <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" />
</div>
```

CSS to style it left justified:

```
.form-element label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
```